# Is it possible to set a maximum character per line in the output of a program

Tags: java, format, output

I am trying to write a program that would output an essay. I am simply suing System.out.print(); functions for each individual sentence with \t in the beginning of each paragraph and \n at the end of each paragraph.

So it would look something like this:

```
System.out.print("\tParagraph 1 Sentence 1");
System.out.print("Paragraph 1 Sentence 2");
System.out.print("Paragraph 1 Sentence 3");
System.out.print("Paragraph 1 Sentence 4\n");

System.out.print("\tParagraph 2 Sentence 2");
System.out.print("Paragraph 2 Sentence 2");
System.out.print("Paragraph 2 Sentence 3");
System.out.print("Paragraph 2 Sentence 4\n");
```

But this would print out each paragraph on a single line.

I was wondering if it is possible to set a maximum amount of characters that get printed per line so that it would auto return as if I was typing it in Word.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Print in what exactly? A GUI widget? The console? Other?

Comment: Without breaking up a word on two lines?

Comment: just the console, and yes without breaking a word into two lines

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to tell the API to add line breaks after 80 characters or anything like that.

You'll have to roll your own "paragraph printer" that keeps track of how many characters have been printed since the beginning of the line, and then output a newline character.

Here's something to give you an idea of what I mean:

```
    String[] paragraphs = {
        "Paragraph 1 Sentence 1. Paragraph 1 Sentence 2. Paragraph 1 Sentence 3. Paragraph 1 Sentence 4.",
        "Paragraph 2 Sentence 1. Paragraph 2 Sentence 2. Paragraph 2 Sentence 3. Paragraph 2 Sentence 4"
    };

    for (String paragraph : paragraphs) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(paragraph);
        System.out.print("        "); // instead of \t
        int col = 8;
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String word = s.next();
            if (col + word.length() > 50) {
                System.out.println();
                col = 0;
            }
            System.out.print(word + " ");
            col += word.length() + 1;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

**Output:**

```
        Paragraph 1 Sentence 1. Paragraph 1 
Sentence 2. Paragraph 1 Sentence 3. Paragraph 1 
Sentence 4. 
        Paragraph 2 Sentence 1. Paragraph 2 
Sentence 2. Paragraph 2 Sentence 3. Paragraph 2 
Sentence 4
```

Comment: That's not exactly true; you can for instance implement your own `Writer` which inserts line breaks where appropriate, but of course such a `Writer` cannot account for unprintable code points on the final display...

Comment: That's pretty much what I said, no? There's nothing in the API, you need to write it yourself.

Comment: Yes but you don't tell how; and your code extract doesn't "exploit" `Writer`, which is what should be done here

Comment: Why would you have to use a `Writer`? I said the code is something to get the OP started. I never said it was a production quality solution, did I?

Comment: Indeed the OP didn't; nevertheless, as a seasoned Java dev, one may provide "monkey patch" code, but also provide hints as to how to do it properly. That is all!

Comment: Thank you guys very much, I am planning on submitting this as a college application, and I think i just might have it run printing each paragraph out on a single line.

Comment: @fge, you have to realize that rolling your own `Writer` might be far beyond what is comprehensible and pedagogical for a beginner. After a couple of years on SO I've learned how to read between the lines and pick up what level is appropriate. The fact that you talk about *"account for unprintable code points"* shows that you don't. @BrianChoromanski, let me know if you want me to expand on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something similar to Word, then you probably want to use a code that does more than just simply split a line (**wrap it**, as normally called by text editors) given a maximum number of characters (which could be easily implemented using a couple of methods from the String class such as *[split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)* and possibly a *[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)*).

For that matter I would suggest you then to use the Line Boundaries sample code from "The Java Tutorials" (from Oracle): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/line.html

As mentioned in the page, the sample is locale-independent code, so it should probably be enough to fulfill your needs.